# How to pass hbase-site.xml to Google Cloud Dataflow template

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, hbase, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a setup where we have a Hbase cluster running on Google cloud and using Dataflow I want to write into Hbase tables. For this, I want to pass my `hbase-site.xml` file in staging and then in prod, I will pass different `hbase-site.xml` in production environment. However, I am not able to find an option to pass a resource file to Dataflow template. Is there any option in Dataflow similar to `--files` in Spark or `--classpath` in Flink for adding this.

I can definitely add `hbase-site.xml` to `src/main/resources` which helps but I want different `hbase-site.xml` for two different environments. So, having an option like this would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Beam [HBaseIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/hbase/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/hbase/HBaseIO.java) and is it possible to pass these parameters as a part of the `Configuration` provided to it ? If so, you could probably update your template to accept this config (or values for creating a config) as a PipelineOption (and parse them in the Main class).

If you want the file to be available locally (in the VM), you probably need to setup a [custom container](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) to be used by your template.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For one use case, it might work but we also have phoenix for which it doesn't straight away work. Also, setting these configs in code is not sensible approach as it may be changed by system admins. I would rather prefer to refer to that file from cluster itself or some central location.
We do use container but let me see if I can add jar file from this container.